# Look for x in line and output line to file

Tags: python

I am making a program to find x in a line and then copy that line and output it to a file together with all the other lines which contain x.

The code that I have for it is this:

```
def output_results(filtered, filename, invalid):

    new_file = open(filename[:4] + "_filtered" + ".txt", "w+")

    for line in filtered:
        new_file.write(line)

    print("Created new file containing", invalid, "lines")
    input()



def start_program():

    whitelisted = ['@tiscali.co.uk', '@talktalk.net', '@screaming.net',
                     '@lineone.net', '@ukgateway.net', '@tinyonline.co.uk', '@tinyworld.co.uk',
                   '@blueyonder.co.uk', '@virginmedia.com', '@ntlworld.com', '@homechoice.co.uk']
    filtered = []
    invalid = 0
    filename = input("Please enter file name: ") + ".txt"

    try:

        with open(filename, "r") as ins:
            for line in ins:
                if any(item in line for item in whitelisted):
                    filtered.append(line)
                else:
                    invalid += 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e) + "\n")
        start_program()


    output_results(filtered, filename, invalid)

start_program()
```

When I run the program and want to look through a text file named "hello.txt" I'll put in the name "hello" but then I get this error

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yes.txt'

I tried to fill in the entire path, I put both the program and the text file in the same folder but it's not working. It is however working for my friend on his PC

Comment: specify abs path of the file

Comment: What line is causing this issue?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, I tried putting the file in the cwd too using print(os.getcwd()) but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `resolve()` method of the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to automatically return the absolute path of the file :

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = input("Please enter file name: ") + ".txt"
filename_abs = Path(filename).resolve()

try:
    with open(filename_abs, "r") as ins:
```

Comment: Then check the access rights to the folder and files or put the files in a public folder and test again. Either that or your antivirus software or whatever is blocking your script from accessing the file.

Comment: I don't have an antivirus, it's all in a public folder. I tried putting them in the same folder on my desktop, I tried puting them in my downloads folder but nothing seems to work. Could I maybe tell the program the path of the file directly?